# Loop Twitter feed via Javascript

Tags: javascript, twitter, feed

Wonder if anyone can help;

I have this code based on twitter post fetcher code;

It displays the tweets one by one and it works great however; but once it reaches the max number of tweets defined in the code it displays undefined; or if it reaches the point of the feed where people have to click to load more;

IS there a way to get it to loop? for example if I set the max tweets to 10 as below and get it to go to loop through the 10 instead of show undefined?

Appreciate for your help

```js
/*********************************************************************
*  #### Twitter Post Fetcher v13.1 ####
*  Coded by Jason Mayes 2015. A present to all the developers out there.
*  www.jasonmayes.com
*  Please keep this disclaimer with my code if you use it. Thanks. :-)
*  Got feedback or questions, ask here:
*  http://www.jasonmayes.com/projects/twitterApi/
*  Github: https://github.com/jasonmayes/Twitter-Post-Fetcher
*  Updates will be posted to this site.
*********************************************************************/
(function(w,p){"function"===typeof define&&define.amd?define([],p):"object"===typeof exports?module.exports=p():p()})(this,function(){function w(a){return a.replace(/<b[^>]*>(.*?)<\/b>/gi,function(a,g){return g}).replace(/class=".*?"|data-query-source=".*?"|dir=".*?"|rel=".*?"/gi,"")}function p(a){a=a.getElementsByTagName("a");for(var c=a.length-1;0<=c;c--)a[c].setAttribute("target","_blank")}function n(a,c){for(var g=[],f=new RegExp("(^| )"+c+"( |$)"),h=a.getElementsByTagName("*"),b=0,k=h.length;b<
k;b++)f.test(h[b].className)&&g.push(h[b]);return g}var B="",k=20,C=!0,u=[],x=!1,v=!0,q=!0,y=null,z=!0,D=!0,A=null,E=!0,F=!1,r=!0,G=!0,m=null,H={fetch:function(a){void 0===a.maxTweets&&(a.maxTweets=20);void 0===a.enableLinks&&(a.enableLinks=!0);void 0===a.showUser&&(a.showUser=!0);void 0===a.showTime&&(a.showTime=!0);void 0===a.dateFunction&&(a.dateFunction="default");void 0===a.showRetweet&&(a.showRetweet=!0);void 0===a.customCallback&&(a.customCallback=null);void 0===a.showInteraction&&(a.showInteraction=
!0);void 0===a.showImages&&(a.showImages=!1);void 0===a.linksInNewWindow&&(a.linksInNewWindow=!0);void 0===a.showPermalinks&&(a.showPermalinks=!0);if(x)u.push(a);else{x=!0;B=a.domId;k=a.maxTweets;C=a.enableLinks;q=a.showUser;v=a.showTime;D=a.showRetweet;y=a.dateFunction;A=a.customCallback;E=a.showInteraction;F=a.showImages;r=a.linksInNewWindow;G=a.showPermalinks;var c=document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0];null!==m&&c.removeChild(m);m=document.createElement("script");m.type="text/javascript";m.src=
"https://cdn.syndication.twimg.com/widgets/timelines/"+a.id+"?&lang="+(a.lang||"en")+"&callback=twitterFetcher.callback&suppress_response_codes=true&rnd="+Math.random();c.appendChild(m)}},callback:function(a){var c=document.createElement("div");c.innerHTML=a.body;"undefined"===typeof c.getElementsByClassName&&(z=!1);a=[];var g=[],f=[],h=[],b=[],m=[],t=[],e=0;if(z)for(c=c.getElementsByClassName("tweet");e<c.length;){0<c[e].getElementsByClassName("retweet-credit").length?b.push(!0):b.push(!1);if(!b[e]||
b[e]&&D)a.push(c[e].getElementsByClassName("e-entry-title")[0]),m.push(c[e].getAttribute("data-tweet-id")),g.push(c[e].getElementsByClassName("p-author")[0]),f.push(c[e].getElementsByClassName("dt-updated")[0]),t.push(c[e].getElementsByClassName("permalink")[0]),void 0!==c[e].getElementsByClassName("inline-media")[0]?h.push(c[e].getElementsByClassName("inline-media")[0]):h.push(void 0);e++}else for(c=n(c,"tweet");e<c.length;)a.push(n(c[e],"e-entry-title")[0]),m.push(c[e].getAttribute("data-tweet-id")),
g.push(n(c[e],"p-author")[0]),f.push(n(c[e],"dt-updated")[0]),t.push(n(c[e],"permalink")[0]),void 0!==n(c[e],"inline-media")[0]?h.push(n(c[e],"inline-media")[0]):h.push(void 0),0<n(c[e],"retweet-credit").length?b.push(!0):b.push(!1),e++;a.length>k&&(a.splice(k,a.length-k),g.splice(k,g.length-k),f.splice(k,f.length-k),b.splice(k,b.length-k),h.splice(k,h.length-k),t.splice(k,t.length-k));c=[];e=a.length;for(b=0;b<e;){if("string"!==typeof y){var d=f[b].getAttribute("datetime"),l=new Date(f[b].getAttribute("datetime").replace(/-/g,
"/").replace("T"," ").split("+")[0]),d=y(l,d);f[b].setAttribute("aria-label",d);if(a[b].innerText)if(z)f[b].innerText=d;else{var l=document.createElement("p"),I=document.createTextNode(d);l.appendChild(I);l.setAttribute("aria-label",d);f[b]=l}else f[b].textContent=d}d="";C?(r&&(p(a[b]),q&&p(g[b])),q&&(d+='<div class="user">'+w(g[b].innerHTML)+"</div>"),d+='<p class="tweet">'+w(a[b].innerHTML)+"</p>",v&&(d=G?d+('<p class="timePosted"><a href="'+t[b]+'">'+f[b].getAttribute("aria-label")+"</a></p>"):
d+('<p class="timePosted">'+f[b].getAttribute("aria-label")+"</p>"))):a[b].innerText?(q&&(d+='<p class="user">'+g[b].innerText+"</p>"),d+='<p class="tweet">'+a[b].innerText+"</p>",v&&(d+='<p class="timePosted">'+f[b].innerText+"</p>")):(q&&(d+='<p class="user">'+g[b].textContent+"</p>"),d+='<p class="tweet">'+a[b].textContent+"</p>",v&&(d+='<p class="timePosted">'+f[b].textContent+"</p>"));E&&(d+='<p class="interact"><a href="https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?in_reply_to='+m[b]+'" class="twitter_reply_icon"'+
(r?' target="_blank">':">")+'Reply</a><a href="https://twitter.com/intent/retweet?tweet_id='+m[b]+'" class="twitter_retweet_icon"'+(r?' target="_blank">':">")+'Retweet</a><a href="https://twitter.com/intent/favorite?tweet_id='+m[b]+'" class="twitter_fav_icon"'+(r?' target="_blank">':">")+"Favorite</a></p>");F&&void 0!==h[b]&&(l=h[b],void 0!==l?(l=l.innerHTML.match(/data-srcset="([A-z0-9%_\.-]+)/i)[0],l=decodeURIComponent(l).split('"')[1]):l=void 0,d+='<div class="media"><img src="'+l+'" alt="Image from tweet" /></div>');
c.push(d);b++}if(null===A){a=c.length;g=0;f=document.getElementById(B);for(h="<ul>";g<a;)h+="<li>"+c[g]+"</li>",g++;f.innerHTML=h+"</ul>"}else A(c);x=!1;0<u.length&&(H.fetch(u[0]),u.splice(0,1))}};return window.twitterFetcher=H});


/**
 * ### HOW TO CREATE A VALID ID TO USE: ###
 * Go to www.twitter.com and sign in as normal, go to your settings page.
 * Go to "Widgets" on the left hand side.
 * Create a new widget for what you need eg "user time line" or "search" etc.
 * Feel free to check "exclude replies" if you don't want replies in results.
 * Now go back to settings page, and then go back to widgets page and
 * you should see the widget you just created. Click edit.
 * Look at the URL in your web browser, you will see a long number like this:
 * 345735908357048478
 * Use this as your ID below instead!
 */

/**
 * How to use TwitterFetcher's fetch function:
 * 
 * @function fetch(object) Fetches the Twitter content according to
 *     the parameters specified in object.
 * 
 * @param object {Object} An object containing case sensitive key-value pairs
 *     of properties below.
 * 
 * You may specify at minimum the following two required properties:
 * 
 * @param object.id {string} The ID of the Twitter widget you wish
 *     to grab data from (see above for how to generate this number).
 * @param object.domId {string} The ID of the DOM element you want
 *     to write results to.
 *
 * You may also specify one or more of the following optional properties
 *     if you desire:
 *
 * @param object.maxTweets [int] The maximum number of tweets you want
 *     to return. Must be a number between 1 and 20. Default value is 20.
 * @param object.enableLinks [boolean] Set false if you don't want
 *     urls and hashtags to be hyperlinked.
 * @param object.showUser [boolean] Set false if you don't want user
 *     photo / name for tweet to show.
 * @param object.showTime [boolean] Set false if you don't want time of tweet
 *     to show.
 * @param object.dateFunction [function] A function you can specify
 *     to format date/time of tweet however you like. This function takes
 *     a JavaScript date as a parameter and returns a String representation
 *     of that date.
 * @param object.showRetweet [boolean] Set false if you don't want retweets
 *     to show.
 * @param object.customCallback [function] A function you can specify
 *     to call when data are ready. It also passes data to this function
 *     to manipulate them yourself before outputting. If you specify
 *     this parameter you must output data yourself!
 * @param object.showInteraction [boolean] Set false if you don't want links
 *     for reply, retweet and favourite to show.
 * @param object.showImages [boolean] Set true if you want images from tweet
 *     to show.
 * @param object.lang [string] The abbreviation of the language you want to use
 *     for Twitter phrases like "posted on" or "time ago". Default value
 *     is "en" (English).
 */

// ##### Advanced example #####
// An advance example to get latest 5 posts using hashtag #API and write to a
// HTML element with id "tweets2" without showing user details and using a
// custom format to display the date/time of the post, and does not show
// retweets.
var config4 = {
    "id": '638725381294551040',
    "domId": 'twitterfeed',
 "showUser": false,
    "maxTweets": 10,
    "enableLinks": true,
    "customCallback": gotTweets
};
twitterFetcher.fetch(config4);

var tweets = [];
var i = 0;
function gotTweets(data){
    tweets = data;
};
function showNextTweet() {
    document.getElementById("twitterfeed").innerHTML = tweets[i];
    i++;
    console.log("Showing tweet " + (i+1));
}
setInterval(showNextTweet, 4000);
```

```html
<div id="twitterfeed"><br>loading tweets</div>
```

Comment: Yes basically I want to loop them - I'll see if that works - thanks for helping

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what you are asking, it would help if you would be more specific. Maybe this is what you want (however simple it might be):

```js
function showNextTweet() {
    // Reset your counter
    if(i >= tweets.length) {
        i = 0;
    }        
    document.getElementById("twitterfeed").innerHTML = tweets[i];
    i++;
    console.log("Showing tweet " + (i+1));
}
```